# Compute failed? Why?

Tags: freecad

I'm using (as pure beginner, please be respectful to my little knowledge in this topic) FreeCAD v0.21.1 for a simple design I wish to 3D print.

This is how it looks like from the front (at least partially):

[image]

Text is made with *ShapeText* and I applied a small *Pocket* onto it in Part Design:

[image]

I have many operations after this text pocket in the tree.

I'm satisfied with my results.

I however wished to make another one, with different text, so I followed a tutorial to copy my whole "Body_of_ND32" to a new "Body_of_ND16":

[image]

After this operation, I have got an error complaining "Recompute failed", and text pocket is containing the original "ND32" pocket, instead my new value.

Of course, I could rebuild the whole thing from scratch adding the text only at the end, to keep everything in shape, but can I somehow detect what's wrong with the recomputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Recompute failed" is not your fault. Freecad is a free CAD software that is maintained by more than 400 volunteers. It is a bug in the software and happens often, for example because of floating point rounding errors. Just moving or changing a shape or body a tiny amount might fix the problem. It could happen when intersecions happen exactly on a line, outlines make a shape self-intersect or beveled objects produce unexpected results or for other unexpected reasons. If you see a pattern in the cause of the error, you might file a [bug report](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/issues)